# Creating an ASP.NET MVC app from scratch

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, svn

So far i've only been using webforms. But me and my friend would like to try out the MVC architecture. Some questions:

- Is there any downside with the free version of visual studio VS professional? I can get the professional version from work but is it worth the effort?
- I would like to use Entity Framework and the latest version of MVC + the razor view engine. Does this need to be downloaded separatly?
- As far as versioning is concerned; is tortoise SVN suitable for a small project on 2 persons?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can't use certain (very useful) plugins. I don't believe you get integrated unit testing. I wouldn't call these "deal breakers" though...

Comment: @EdSF Does this include third party plugins like Resharper?

Comment: I honestly don't know - I use VS Pro...my comment is based on an experience I had with a colleague some time ago and found out about certain limitations (as expected) on free versions. It is a great way to get started (and it will not be a barrier) and you should be able to get going. If you need more power, you can always think about moving up at some later time (larger projects, unit tests, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVN is ok as a repository in my experience. If you are using Visual Studio there is a decent plugin so you can use it from within the IDE, rather than from within Windows. If I am using SVN, it is what I use! More details [here](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/).

MVC3 can be downloaded [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3)

Entity Framework can be installed via Nuget (PM> Install-Package EntityFramework ) or a quick google will show the download locations (I think there is version 4.3 and a CTP of version 5)

Answer (score 0):

1. Free version will work, not sure if there are any differences.
2. Yes you need to download it seperately
3. Why wouldn;t it be?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. It's a good way to start. I know earlier versions didn't allow plugins but not sure about the latest versions.

EF will come with the .NET SDK (VS) so no need there. You can get MVC3 from the Web Platform Installer (http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3)

I use Tortoise SVN on a team of 4 people with no issues at all. Just make sure you all know good rules for source control management.